# How to make sure that Selected Item for Gridrow selection is notified first before combobox selected item inside a Grid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a collection that is bound to a `GridView` and another collection that is bound to a `ComboBox`.

My `ComboBox` is under a cell template and is inside a row in my GridView.

Each collection has a selected item. One for `GridView` and one for the `ComboBox`.

When I select the ComboBox item I want to make sure that the selected row is notified first before notifying my ComboBox selected item.

Is this sound possible in MVVM?

Code added:

ViewModel

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets selected row in datagrid
    /// </summary>
    public RowObject SelectedRow
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedRow == null ? new RowObject() : _selectedRow;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedRow = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedRow);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets and sets the selected combobox item.
    /// </summary>
    public ComboBoxObject SelectedComboboxItem
    {
        get
        {
            return (_selectedComboboxItem == null ? new ComboboxObject() : _selectedComboboxItem );
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) return;
            if (value == _selectedComboboxItem ) return;

            _selectedComboboxItem = value;  

            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SelectedComboboxItem);
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfRowObjects}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

INSIDE GRIDROW IS A COMBOBOX

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" Header="Product">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfComboboxItem, 
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboboxItem >
```

Comment: Have you tried ANYTHING? Pretty much "everything" is possible in the world of programming, if that's your question...

Comment: WPF has a concept called [RoutedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx). RoutedEvents contains events strategy called `Tunneling` which lets the root element handle it first, and then tunnle all the way down the it's creator. since your `ComboxBox` is inside the Grid, you can use Tunneling events the handle it in the grid before it is handled in the `ComboBox` ...

Comment: Consider adding code snippets to simplify your question. this would make the answers more precise ...

Comment: Thanks Omri.  I've updated this question.